# Can't find a current JQuery spellcheck plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, spell-checking

The most popular spellcheck plugin on stackoverflow seems to be https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker but it is no longer maintained and stagnant for 2 years...

Are there any solid spellcheckers that have come forward since that one faded out?  I need one for a textarea field on my Rails 4 app.

Comment: I take it you're not interested in larger plugins that extend the `textarea` while also including spell chekers, like TinyMCE, CKEditor or Aloha?

Comment: That's correct.  My user is only typing standard text so I don't need the mark up, but do need spellcheck functionality.

Comment: @Stevangelista have you seen anything that built a layer over those types of plug ins to enable, as an example, a drag and drop anchor tag but not straight HTML?

Comment: Whats wrong with the native spell checker? fubar http://skitch.shanimal.com/spellcheck_196E3E17.png

Comment: Any update about this?